# Adding child to rigidbody makes it move

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a parent object with a rigidbody (gravity disabled). With a script I am adding simple cubes with box colliders as children to this parent.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Test : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject prefab;

    void Update()
    {
        if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            GameObject go = Instantiate(prefab, transform);
            go.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(10f, 10f, 10f);
        }
    }
}
```

This works fine, but a slight movement of the parent object is visible everytime a cube is instantiated and parented. So eventually after adding quite a few cubes the parent moves even whole units from its original position, although the velocity is always Vector3.zero.

How does this movement happen and how do I prevent it?

Comment: What does the location identifying the position actually represent?  For example, if it were something like center of mass, then that would change as you add children, and the collection would move even if the numbers for the position didn't change.

Comment: It certainly does not represent the center of mass, because the parent keeps moving in one specific direction as I add more and more children. It just represents the world space position of the rigidbody. But it seems like the movement is only happening if a object changes its position while it is child of the rigidbody. So if I first set the position and then set the parent, no movement.

Comment: So it sounds like you have solved the problem.

Comment: Indeed. Problem is the transformation of the parent does not apply to children anymore. But I can fix that with transform.TransformPoint() and transform.InverseTransformPoint(). Thanks for the help

Comment: I would recommend posting (and accepting!) your solution as an answer (yes, answering your own question is perfectly legit).

Comment: I am not quite happy with the solution of deparenting, repositioning and then parenting again. First, because it has to be done in many places in my code which pobably is costly and confusing and also feels more like a hack. Also I have to fiddle around a lot so that the transformations match with the ones already applied to the parent. I am just confused why there is this movement in the first place. I also noticed that the child has to have a collider in order for the movement of the rigidbody to occur. So maybe that would be another try, but still not an answer to why this even happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it appears that the small movement of the rigidbody parent comes from a change in the centre of mass. By moving or instantiating objects as childs this value has been changed as it states in https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-centerOfMass.html:

> If you don't set the center of mass from a script it will be
> calculated automatically from all colliders attached to the rigidbody.
> After a custom center of mass set, it will no longer be recomputed
> automatically on modifications such as adding or removing colliders,
> translating them, scaling etc. To revert back to the automatically
> computed center of mass, use Rigidbody.ResetCenterOfMass.

Finally, as solution I just set the local center of mass to a fixed value.

```
rig.centerOfMass = Vector3.zero;
```

I am quite happy with this solution, because this also changes the center of rotation. Still I am not quite sure **why** it adds a movement on a change in the center of mass, because I don't see why that would be realistic behaviour.

Also there is a difference between rigidbody.position and transform.position. By  using solutions such as commented under the question:

- Unparent, move child, parent again
- Disable child, move child, enable child again
- Disable the child's collider, move child, enable it again

...it is possible to keep the transform.position the same, but rigidbody.position will still change. This difference between both values persists as long as the rigidbody is asleep. Waking it up e.g. by calling `Rigidbody.Wakeup()` will sync both values again. Due to a difference in both values even things like a raycast can fail, although the ray might be hitting the spot where the meshes are actually drawn and just the physics engine thinks they are somewhere else. Also waking up again looks ugly because the mesh snaps back into place were it should be to match the rigidbody.